# Remove dynamic segment information from route emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

I have an ember engine, and within that I have defined a route. It works as expected. It's called `my-route`. It was defined like this:

`this.route('my-route', {path: '/my-route/:myparams'});` in the `routes.js` file.

As you can see, it has a dynamic segment, and shows different values based on `myparams`.

I want to add a nested `route` to this `route`. Let's say `.../my-route/1` shows a list of items. When the user clicks on any of the items listed on the page, the route should be: `my-route/display` but instead its `my-route/1/display`. I don't want the `1` here as it could be misleading.

Also, the `link-to` doesn't open anything either, the click does nothing.
This is how I changed my `routes.js`file:

`this.route('my-route', {path: '/my-route/:myparams'}, function() {
      this.route('display');
 });`

In `display.hbs` file I added dummy data, and `display.js` is also empty, just extending from `Ember.route`.
The `my-route.hbs` links like this:

`{{#link-to 'my-route.display'}} Open me {{/link-to}}'`

I am new to EmberJS, and would appreciate if someone could please tell me how to:

1. Remove the dynamic segment information
2. Make the `link-to` work

Thank you!

Comment: I think you have a X-Y Problem. Why would `/my-route/1` show a *list* of items? It should show things of the item `1`. Please tell more about what you want to display, and why you want to nest the routes as you said. Probably something is wrong with your nesting.

Comment: I want to show lists with `my-route/param` and then clicking on one of the items, opens up the actual item. Maybe I should revisit my design then?

Comment: but the list of items on `my-route/param` is related to the `param`? And then if you show the actual item its no longer related to param? And is your UI nested. Probably just don't nest the routes. If your UI is not nested, don't nest your routes.

Comment: Yes, it is related to `param`. Yes, it won't be any longer related to the param when actual item will be shown. The problem would be I have one route called `list` and the other `display`. Then there would be no need of `my-route`. How would I manage that?

Comment: Yep. Then don't use `my-route`. Why do you want `my-route`?

Comment: I need it there in the URL to show the structure. What can I do to have it in the URL? A dummy route?

Comment: just specify the path. You *can* do `this.route('param', { path: '/my-route/:id' })` and `this.route('list', {path: '/my-route/list'})`.

Answer (score 1):

1) I can think of no easy way to remove dynamic segment from the url -- if you must, you can probably just not use dynamic segment and send the information to the transitioning route via other ways - you can probably set the controller directly
 "newRoute.controller.set('someProperty', my_param);"
or use needs api (http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/)

but note that both these methods would be making use of controllers. If you need to load data in the route depending on the query params, what comes to mind is using a service

But these methods are not very sophisticated and I'd say only go for it if dynamic segment is an absolute no.

2) this one is easier -- you need to pass in the dynamic part along with the route name when using link to -- as given in ember guide
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/templates/links/

Comment: thinking of it, you could also use the info from the url, then change the url. but again, that might show the url with dynamic segment for a while. also a lot of extra work

Comment: Thanks Chhirag, I'll get back to you for question 1. But for second question, the URL does change: `...my-route/1/display`, but it doesn't go to display, it reloads `my-route`. What could I be doing wrong, can you please tell?

Comment: Taking a closer look, you should probably move your dynamic segment part to display route, and pass in the dynamic segment via link-to helper (look at the ember guide link above, the example should be similar)

something like this.route('my-route', function() {
      this.route('display', {path: '/my-route/:myparams'});
 });

{{#link-to 'my-route.display' displayparam}}

Comment: So the way I am doing it, won't actually even render the link?

Comment: correct - because it needs a dynamic segment, which you aren't passing at all

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussions with @Lux and @Chhirag Kataria, I ended up making two separate routes. I used the `my-route` as a dummy route, and nested the `display` and the `list` routes in it.